# fbx parser/loader for java exists?

Tags: java, parsing, model

I'm building an interactive program in java, but I need to extract animation from an object. Yes, I could do it by keyframing each animation, but the number of files (plus processing) adds up real quick.

Is there a way to parse/load an **fbx** file similar to parsing/loading a **obj** file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a java implementation but here is a Python binary FBX parser (single python script ~150 lines), its quite easy to port.

http://github.com/ideasman42/pyfbx_i42

Edit, direct link to source file:

http://github.com/ideasman42/pyfbx_i42/blob/master/pyfbx/parse_bin.py